# Suggestion on a way to locate elements in tableau report displayed in salesforce

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation

Below is the rendered report that i'm trying to validate.I tried locating by xpath,id's using browser inspector but did not work out.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code what you tried?